# illegal start of type/ cannot find symbol error

Tags: javascript

I'm new at Javascript so please understand that I don't really know what I am doing. I had a "illegal start of type" error message pop up at the "if" strand of code, so I put the "void a Method" statement and the error went away. But the other error messages are "cannon find symbol" for "age". I don't know what to do. I welcome any help! Here is a part of my code:

```
     // Put code for displayJButtonActionPerformed
void aMethod(){
if (age<=10)
{
    displayJLabel.setText("SpringChicken");
}
else if (age >10 && <= 15)
{
    displayJLabel.setText("SummerChicken");
}
else if (age >15 && <= 20)
{
    displayJLabel.setText("KentuckyFriedChicken");
}
}
//
```

Comment: Use `function aMethod(){` instead of `void aMethod(){`

Comment: `age >10 && <= 15` => `age >10 && age <= 15`

Comment: `age >10` and `age >15` are useless, they would have been catched in the previous `if`

Comment: Ok, thanks! Ill try these suggestions right away

Comment: `age` is also never initialized. and you're not passing it as a parameter.